# How can I compare text in an SQLite database to some text held locally in a text file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite

I have a program which **gets the history in Google Chrome** from Chrome's `SQLite database`. It works great, and the result is this:

[image: Image of the program.]

which uses **this code:**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim google As String = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History")
        Dim fileName As String = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString
        File.Copy(google, (Application.StartupPath + ("\" + fileName)))
        Dim con As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection(("DataSource = " + (Application.StartupPath + ("\" + (fileName + ";Versio=3;New=False;Compress=True;")))))
        Dim da As SQLiteDataAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc", con)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Now, here's what's giving me trouble:

**How can I compare the database URL text to a locally hosted .txt file which has a list of whitelisted websites?**

Here's what I've researched so far which is part of the structure of this program:

```
Dim file As String
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("websitelist.txt").ToString

If file.Contains("exampledomain.com") Then // from SQLite Database
    MessageBox.Show("A query exists in the database.")
End If
```

How can I do this *but* working with **SQLite**?

> Any information you need, please, comment below.

Comment: Can't you put the whitelist into a (temporary) table?

Comment: How do you want to compare? Do you want all the matches? The ones in history that are not on the white list? What result do you want?

Comment: I want to scan the database for all of the URL entries. If any of the URL's are the same as what is in a locally held whitelist .txt file,  a MessageBox will popup. @Mary

Comment: So you don't care which ones match, only that at least one matches?

Comment: I do care which ones match. @Mary

Comment: First, you should not see the whitelist as a file, but as a list. You load the file into a list of strings, and then with LINQ you can something like WHERE WhiteList.Any(DbUrl) don't remember the exact syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Using...End Using blocks to ensure that your objects are closed and disposed properly even it there is an error. I just used a DataTable and a DataReader to lighten things up a bit. Add the url field to a List(Of T) Then with a Linq query get the data that matches. I just printed it out to the Immediate window but you can use it any way you need to.

```
Private Sub btnGoogleHistory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGoogleHistory.Click
        Dim google As String = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History")
        Dim fileName As String = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString
        File.Copy(google, (Application.StartupPath + ("\" + fileName)))
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Using con As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection($"DataSource = {Application.StartupPath }\{fileName};Versio=3;New=False;Compress=True;")
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc ", con)
                con.Open()
                Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Dim lstGoogleHistory As New List(Of String)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            lstGoogleHistory.Add(row("url").ToString)
        Next
        Dim WhiteListText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("websitelist.txt").ToString
        Dim InWhiteList = From uri In lstGoogleHistory
                          Where uri.All(Function(x) WhiteListText.Contains(uri))
                          Select uri
        For Each URL In InWhiteList
            Debug.Print(URL)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Works, but I want it to read the database, not the DataGridView. Or, have I mis-read, and is it doing so?

Comment: It is reading from an in memory DataTable. You can get rid of the DataGridView entirely if you wish. You have to get the data out of the database and put it somewhere in order to work with it.

Comment: Ok thanks! Work's great! I have one more question. If a whitelisted page is found, how can I redirect chrome traffic to a different domain?

Comment: Sorry, that would be a new question. I do not know how to control Chrome. I was happy to save your code for getting the History. Will upvote your question since I saved the code.

Comment: Or close chromes tab and re-open to a different website. I could use `Process.Start("whatever.com")` after I close the tab, but, how would I do that? @Mary

Comment: I really don't know. If you try some code and it doesn't work, post a new question showing your code.